# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

Have no idea what's wrong here!!

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

my hosted file at mydomain.com/facebook

my app setting

- App Domains: mydomain.com
- Website with Facebook Login :  mydomain.com/facebook

Comment: Have you tried Website with Facebook Login : mydomain.com (without the Facebook subdir)